# ng2-toastr not working when navigated to different page

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router

I am using [ng2-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr) to display notification messages. I works fine when i am in the same page but when i navigate to another route it will not appear on the new page

I set the route for the `ViewContainerRef` inside the main component of my app

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  public constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef);
  }
}
```

`sub component.ts`

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

 constructor(
    public toastr: ToastsManager,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    private tripService: TripService) {
      this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
 }

...
login() {
this.toastr.success('User Create Successfully !!..');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  public constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;

    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef);
  }
}
```

**sub.component.ts**

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

 constructor(
    public toastr: ToastsManager,
    private tripService: TripService) {
 }

...
login() {
this.toastr.success('User Create Successfully !!..');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

I hope this helps you. You don't need to import ViewContainerRef in each and every component.

Answer (score 0):

You should call out the module in the app.module.ts

**TS**

```
imports: [
//    
ToastModule.forRoot()
//
]
```

and call the TosterService in whichever component you need to use.

```
 constructor(public ts: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
     this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }

this.ts.success(//MESSAGE);
this.ts.error(//MESSAGE)
```